# What is the signature/type for FirestoreDataConverter.fromFirestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have a newly installed js application with versions:

```
"firebase": "^7.14.0",
"firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
```

I'm attempting to use the new (new since I last used firebase for a project) `withConverter()` function on the Document snapshot. However, typescript is complaining that the `fromFirestore` method on the `FirestoreDataConverter` type requires a single argument `data` of type `FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData`. Whereas the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FirestoreDataConverter) and the [codebase](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/f24ddc450e75ce0270ee4c688b6f362fa620a997/packages/firestore-types/index.d.ts#L43) suggest there are two arguments `(snapshot: firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot, options: firebase.firestore.SnapshotOptions)`

So my question is, which one is the signature moving forward? I like the version with the snapshot because I assume I can access the doc.id and pass it to my returned object. This would save an iteration over the returned data.

Here is the fromFirestore type from the IDE perspective:

```
FirebaseFirestore.FirestoreDataConverter<T>.fromFirestore(data: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData): T
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you're looking at is for the client JavaScript SDK.  What you're using, however, is the JavaScript server SDK.  When you import the Firebase Admin SDK, you're actually getting a instance of the Google Cloud node SDK as documented [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/index.html).  The APIs are similar, but not exactly the same, so you should use the server docs, and disregard the client SDK docs.

You can see that [Query.withConverter](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html#withConverter) and [DocumentReference.withConverter](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#withConverter) only accept a single argument.

Comment: The signature will be the same as the client libraries when they merge this PR (drop node 8 support): https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/pull/1006